# Display Text String keep paragraph in TextView/EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, paragraph

I have an Text like this:

```html
⋱ ⋮ ⋰
⋯ ◯ ⋯ ︵ 　　　　　　^v^
¸︵︵( ░░ )︵.︵.︵　　
(´░░░░░░ ') ░░░' )
`´︶´¯`︶´`︶´︶´`　^v^　　^v^
╔┓┏╦━━╦┓╔┓╔━━╗╔╗
║┗┛║┗━╣┃║┃║╯╰║║║
║┏┓║┏━╣┗╣┗╣╰╯║╠╣
╚┛┗╩━━╩━╩━╩━━╝╚╝
♪♫•*¨*•.¸¸❤¸¸.•*¨*•♫♪
```

I want to show it on textview/edittext. I put all text string by copy/paste to my firebase database. And then i get it from firebase to show in textview/edittext. But it doesn't keep the original format/paragraph

Comment: As I look first one is better for me, I don't understand exactly what you are trying to acheive. Please add more details.

Comment: Hello Destrif.Sorry for my bad english. I want to show first one on textview/edittext. but it show like second. it did not keep the paragraph

Comment: Give us the code. of the first and second example.

Comment: i update my question

Comment: Edit it one more time, still not enought prrecise question...
For me the answer is good. Rather Edit it with specific details or we will not be able to help...

Answer (score 1):

Here your Textview just copy & paste it

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="-8dp" // This will reduce vertical space
    android:text="@string/text"/>
```

`@string/text` declared in String.xml

```
 <string name="text">"⋱ ⋮ ⋰"\n"
⋯ ◯ ⋯ ︵ 　　　　　　^v^"\n"
¸︵︵( ░░ )︵.︵.︵"\n"　　
(´░░░░░░ ') ░░░' )"\n"
`´︶´¯`︶´`︶´︶´`　^v^　　^v^"\n"
╔┓┏╦━━╦┓╔┓╔━━╗╔╗"\n"
║┗┛║┗━╣┃║┃║╯╰║║║"\n"
║┏┓║┏━╣┗╣┗╣╰╯║╠╣"\n"
╚┛┗╩━━╩━╩━╩━━╝╚╝"\n"
♪♫•*¨*•.¸¸❤¸¸.•*¨*•♫♪"</string>
```

Comment: thank you, but it does not seem as i want. please see my update question